# Printing a section of a web page, but print out loses all styles?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I'm printing a section of my page from my MVC application with the following javascript code:

```js
function PrintElem(elem) {
  Popup($(elem).html());
}

function Popup(data) {
  var mywindow = window.open("", "divprint", "height=400,width=600");
  mywindow.document.write("<html><head><title></title>");

  /*optional stylesheet*/
  // mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" />'); 

  mywindow.document.write("</head><body >");
  mywindow.document.write(data);
  mywindow.document.write("</body></html>");
  cloneLinksAndStyle(window, newWindow);
  mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
  mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10

  mywindow.print();
  mywindow.close();

  return true;
}
```

HTML:

```html
@model IEnumerable <AljawdahNewSite.Models.Orders_Tables>
  @{
   ViewBag.Title = "MasterDetails";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutPatients.cshtml";
  }

  <h2>Order Result - نتائج التحاليل </h2>
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align:center">
        <input type="submit" value="Print Result - طباعة النتيجة"
               onclick="PrintElem('#divprint')" class="btn btn-danger"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div id="divprint">
    <div style="margin-left:15px">
      <hr/>
      <dl class="horizontal">
        <dt style="width: 20%;display: inline-block;">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model
          => model.labViewResult.Patient_Name)
        </dt>
        <dd
          style="width: 25%;display: inline-block;margin: 0px;margin-left:-50px">
          @Html.DisplayFor(model =>
          model.FirstOrDefault().labViewResult.Patient_Name)
        </dd>
        <dt style="width: 22%;display: inline-block;">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model
          => model.labViewResult.Customer_Name)
        </dt>
        <dd
          style="width: 25%;display: inline-block;margin: 0px;margin-left:0px">
          @Html.DisplayFor(model =>
          model.FirstOrDefault().labViewResult.Customer_Name)
        </dd>
        <dt style="width: 20%;display: inline-block;">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model
          => model.labViewResult.Patient_No)
        </dt>
        <dd
          style="width: 25%;display: inline-block;margin: 0px;margin-left:-50px">
          @Html.DisplayFor(model =>
          model.FirstOrDefault().labViewResult.Patient_No)
        </dd>
        <dt style="width: 22%;display: inline-block;">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model
          => model.labViewResult.Clinic_File_No)
        </dt>
        <dd
          style="width: 20%;display: inline-block;margin: 0px;margin-left:0px">
          @Html.DisplayFor(model =>
          model.FirstOrDefault().labViewResult.Clinic_File_No)
        </dd>
        <dt style="width: 20%;display: inline-block;">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model
          => model.labViewResult.SEX)
        </dt>
        <dd
          style="width: 20%;display: inline-block;margin: 0px;margin-left:-50px">
          @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().labViewResult.SEX)
        </dd>
        <dt style="width: 22%;display: inline-block;margin-left:60px">
          @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.labViewResult.Collection_Date)
        </dt>
        <dd
          style="width: 25%;display: inline-block;margin: 0px;margin-left:0px">
          @Html.DisplayFor(model =>
          model.FirstOrDefault().labViewResult.Collection_Date)
        </dd>
        <dt style="width: 20%;display: inline-block;">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model
          => model.labViewResult.AGE)
        </dt>
        <dd
          style="width: 20%;display: inline-block;margin: 0px;margin-left:-50px">
          @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstOrDefault().labViewResult.AGE)
        </dd>
        <dt style="width: 22%;display: inline-block;margin-left:60px">
          @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.labViewResult.Receiving_Date)
        </dt>
        <dd
          style="width: 25%;display: inline-block;margin: 0px;margin-left:0px">
          @Html.DisplayFor(model =>
          model.FirstOrDefault().labViewResult.Receiving_Date)
        </dd>
        <dt style="width: 20%;display: inline-block;">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model
          => model.labViewResult.order_number)
        </dt>
        <dd
          style="width: 25%;display: inline-block;margin: 0px;margin-left:-50px">
          @Html.DisplayFor(model =>
          model.FirstOrDefault().labViewResult.order_number)
        </dd>

        <dt style="width: 22%;display: inline-block;">@Html.DisplayNameFor(model
          => model.labViewResult.Report_Date)
        </dt>
        <dd
          style="width: 25%;display: inline-block;margin: 0px;margin-left:0px">
          @Html.DisplayFor(model =>
          model.FirstOrDefault().labViewResult.Report_Date)
        </dd>


      </dl>
    </div>

    <div style="align-content:center">
      <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>

          <td> test name</td>
          <td> result</td>
          <td> From Range</td>
          <td> To Range</td>
          <td> Other Range</td>
          <td> Report Date</td>


        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
        <tr>

          <td>@item.labViewResult.Test_Name</td>
          <td>@item.labViewResult.Result</td>
          <td>@item.labViewResult.Low_Range</td>
          <td>@item.labViewResult.High_Range</td>
          <td style="width:20%">@item.labViewResult.Text_Range</td>
          <td>@item.labViewResult.Report_Date</td>


        </tr>
        }
      </table>

      <link href="~/Contents/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    </div>
  </div>
```

My issue is that when I print using javascript, the paper prints without any style. How can I add some style to my printout?

This is the current print out now.

(I'm new to JavaScript)

[image]

These are the CSS files I have linked in the shared layout:

```
<link
  href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,700|Work+Sans:300,400,700"
  rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href=@Url.Content("/Contents/fonts/icomoon/style.css")>
<link rel="stylesheet" href=@Url.Content("/Contents/css/bootstrap.min.css")>
<link rel="stylesheet" href=@Url.Content("/Contents/css/magnific-popup.css")>
<link rel="stylesheet" href=@Url.Content("/Contents/css/jquery-ui.css")>
<link rel="stylesheet" href=@Url.Content("/Contents/css/owl.carousel.min.css")>
<link rel="stylesheet"
      href=@Url.Content("/Contents/css/owl.theme.default.min.css")>
<link rel="stylesheet"
      href=@Url.Content("/Contents/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css")>
<link rel="stylesheet" href=@Url.Content("/Contents/css/animate.css")>

<link rel="stylesheet"
      href=@Url.Content("/Contents/fonts/flaticon/font/flaticon.css")>

<link rel="stylesheet" href=@Url.Content("/Contents/css/aos.css")>
<link rel="stylesheet" href=@Url.Content("/Contents/css/style.css")>
```

Comment: You have to add the same stylesheets to the popup as used in the source page or only use inline styles, I reckon. Maybe it would be easier to open the same page in the popup and hide the areas you do not wish to see in it (with a media print css).

Comment: @Lain how to add it can you give me the example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have styling on the browser page that you want to maintain on the printout.

In order to maintain the same styles in the new window, you can copy the original window's `link` and `style` elements to the new window.

This function will copy all the `link` and `style` elements from one window to another:

```js
function cloneLinksAndStyles (win, newWin) {
  const newHead = newWin.document.head;

  const links = Array.from(win.document.getElementsByTagName("LINK"));
  links.forEach(link => {
    let newLink = newWin.document.createElement('link');
    newLink.rel = 'stylesheet';
    newLink.href = link.href;
    newHead.appendChild(newLink);
  });

  const styles = Array.from(win.document.getElementsByTagName('STYLE'));
  styles.forEach(style => {
    let newStyle = newWin.document.createElement('style');
    newStyle.innerHTML = style.innerHTML;
    newHead.appendChild(newStyle);
  });
}
```

Then, in your script:

```js
function Popup(data) {
  ...
  cloneLinksAndStyle(window, newWindow);
  ...
}
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/terrymorse/hyr0kvgw/14/) to show this working.

Comment: I added this line to popup(data)  myWindow.document.styleSheets = window.document.styleSheets;  but its not printing now , what i need to do more steps , thank you in advance , where i need to add first line window.document.styleSheets;
?

Comment: @Abdullah See my revised method, above. It explicitly copies all the `<style>` and `<link>` elements.

Comment: I added the function and replaced the link and style but still the classes not appeared when print  (table table-bordered) and other classes not appeared in print , is this correct what i did can you check the code once again , and thank you again

Comment: @Abdullah You must have something else wrong with your code, because the code in my answer works. See the jsfiddle in the answer that shows it working correctly.